# Quartz trigger does not fire immediately

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'd like to execute the job ~immediately with quartz scheduler using jdbc datastore. However I have like 20-30 seconds delay between the scheduling and trigger fire even though I schedule with now() or calling triggerJob.

I tried to execute the job with a simple trigger:

```
JobKey key = //...
        JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(jobBean.getClass())
                .withIdentity(key)
                .usingJobData(new JobDataMap(jobParams))
                .storeDurably()
                .build();

        Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(key.getName(), key.getGroup())
                .startNow()
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                        .withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow()
                        .withRepeatCount(0))
                .build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

And I also tried to trigger with scheduler:

```
 JobKey key = // ...
        JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(jobBean.getClass())
                .withIdentity(key)
                .storeDurably()
                .build();
        scheduler.addJob(jobDetail, true);


        scheduler.triggerJob(key, new JobDataMap(jobParams));
```

Here are the listener logs that shows the delay.

```
2019-05-15 13:59:52,066Z  INFO  [nio-8081-exec-2] c.m.f.s.logger.SchedulingListener                  : Job added: newsJobTemplate:1557928791965
2019-05-15 13:59:52,066Z  INFO  [nio-8081-exec-2] c.m.f.s.logger.SchedulingListener                  : Job scheduled: newsJobTemplate:1557928791965
2019-05-15 14:00:18,660Z  INFO  [eduler_Worker-1] c.m.f.s.logger.TriggerStateListener                : Trigger fired: QUARTZ_JOBS.newsJobTemplate:1557928791965 {}
2019-05-15 14:00:18,703Z  INFO  [eduler_Worker-1] c.m.f.s.logger.JobExecutionListener                : Job will be executed: QUARTZ_JOBS.newsJobTemplate:1557928791965
2019-05-15 14:00:19,284Z  INFO  [eduler_Worker-1] c.m.f.s.logger.JobExecutionListener                : Job was executed: QUARTZ_JOBS.newsJobTemplate:1557928791965
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found crumbs here and there that suggested that the problem is transaction related.
So I removed @Transactional from the service method and voila it worked.
Looks like when you call trigger the scheduler thread asyncronously tries to look up schedules and triggers from the DB but the transaction is not committed at that time. Later the scheduler thread looks up the db again and it finds it finally.

Comment: I want to add, that this may be an underliyng change in how Spring manages transactions. As I didn't have this problem in Spring Boot 1, but started to happend after migrating to Spring Boot 2.

Answer (score 1):

zolee's answer describes the problem perfectly, but there are also a few things one can do to solve it.

One imperfect solution is to reduce org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime. In fact, the problem itself is described, though somewhat obliquely, in the [quartz configuration doc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigMain.html), org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime section.

> Normally you should not have to ‘tune’ this parameter, unless you’re
> using XA transactions, and are having problems with delayed firings of
> triggers that should fire immediately.

That will allow you to reduce 30-second delay to 5 seconds or even less.

A full solution is to extend QuartzScheduler to add transaction support. Exact implementation will depend on what library/code you're using for transaction support, but it worked for us perfectly.

```
class TransactionAwareScheduler extends QuartzScheduler {
    @Override
    protected void notifySchedulerThread(long candidateNewNextFireTime) {
        if (insideTransaction) {
            transaction.addCommitHook(() -> {
                super.notifySchedulerThread(candidateNewNextFireTime);
            });
        }
    } else {
        super.notifySchedulerThread(candidateNewNextFireTime);
    }
}
```